# Entity Framework Core Count inside Select

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created a method that filters my dataset. I also created another method that counts the amount of items there are with the filters applied. This method looks like this:

```
return new Count
        {
            Address = this.Filter(/* paramters to filter */)
                .GroupBy(person => person.Address.City)
                .Select(group => new Amount<string>
                {
                    Type = group.Key /* so the city */,
                    Count = group.Count()
                }),
        };
```

Count has a couple of lists of amount objects. The amount objects holds the name of what it will filter on and a count of how many the filter contains.

```
this.Filter()
```

Is a private method that will return an IQueryable from the DbContext.

Everything works, however, it is very slow with a large amount of data. The reason for this is that the GroupBy() and the Count() could not be translated and will be evaluated locally. It gives the following warnings:

```
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
      The LINQ expression 'GroupBy([entity.RequestRating], [entity])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
      The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
      The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
```

What would be a better approach to this? This is a ASP.NET CORE project

Comment: If anyone should can help you, it would be quite necessary to provide the code of the Classes you created and the right using for the classes you didn’t.

Comment: Is this a DbSet or a DbContext?

Comment: You should have called `entity` as `group`. Its bit irritating, suggesting the parameter  may be a single entity. Why do you even need `r => r.Address.City == entity.Key` in the first place?? All you need is actually `.Count()` because you grouped the result already, the groups content all belong to the same city who `group.key` belongs to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var amountList = Persons.Where(paramters to filter)
            .GroupBy(person => person.Address.City)
            .Select(group => new Amount()
            {
                City = group.Key,
                CityCount = group.Count()
            }).Tolist();
```

Comment: This will still not be translated and will be evaluated locally

Comment: Great! to hear that! Welcome!